# Output and error streams on windows console

Tags: java, windows, stream, console, eclipse-rcp

I'm looking for a solution to print the output and error streams on the windows console.

A java program starts a rcp application (.exe) thanks to a command line :

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("example.exe");
```

Example.exe writes something after being started...
Then I want the java program to get the output stream of example.exe.

My problem is that it doesn't work and if I put the 2 eclipse runtime options: `-console` and `-consoleLog`, the output stream is printed in another console so I can't get back the stream...

Any ideas?

Edit: Here is my code to get the outputStream and errorStream (it works for a simple java program but not for a rcp application)

```
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("toto.exe");

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            String line = "";
            try {
                while((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    inputText = inputText + line;
                }
                System.out.println(inputText);

                while((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    errorText = errorText + line;
                }
                System.out.println(errorText);
            } finally {
                errorReader.close();
                inputReader.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: `Process` has `getErrorStream()` and `getInputStream()` methods.

Comment: I already did that (i updated my post) the problem is that my example.exe is started by the dos console and the runtime eclipse option -consoleLog opens a new console (an ogsi console i think) so i can't get the stream like that...